# Problems with having A records as subdomains of a CNAME Record?

Tags: domain-name-system

Are there any implications where an A records as a subdomain of a CNAME record would cause issues resolving.

For Example.

```
$TTL 3600
primary.www.example.com.       IN A     10.0.0.10
secondary.www.example.com.     IN A     10.0.0.10
www.example.com.           300 IN CNAME primary.www.example.com.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I guess with DNAME there's a loop, but otherwise no